# Slurm jobs are pending, but resources are available

Tags: batch, scheduled-tasks, queue-management

I use SLURM as a job scheduler and queue for a small cluster (single node with 64 cores).
To submit a batch job I use:

```
> sbatch run.sh
```

Where run.sh looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash

#SBATCH --ntasks=4

export OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=4
/home/Benchmarks/Graph500/omp-csr/omp-csr -s 23
```

However, when I submit 2 batch jobs one after the other I get:

```
> squeue
     JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
        29     debug   run.sh anonymou PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
        28     debug   run.sh anonymou  R       1:13      1 localhost
```

Each job needs only 4 cores, so both jobs should run.
Maybe I misconfigured the slurm controller, the relevant lines from /etc/slurm.conf are:

```
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=localhost CPUs=64 Sockets=4 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=localhost Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

I would be thankful for any help/hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SLURM by default does not allow resources sharing, so when a job runs in 1 node the rest of the jobs wait for it to complete before executing any further jobs on the same node.

SLURM needs to be configured for resources sharing, this should be fairly simple and well documented.

An example of what to add to your slurm.conf file (normally located under /etc/slurm) would be:

```
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=
DefMemPerCPU=
```

This would allow sharing of the resources of a node using the `con_res` plugin.

The `select/con_res` plugin allows a wide variety of Parameters (SelectTypeParameters). The most prominent are listed below (for a full list of parameters please refer to the manual page of slurm.conf):

**CR_CPU**: CPUs are the consumable resource.
**CR_CPU_Memory**:  adds memory as consumable to CR_CPU.
**CR_Core   Cores**: Cores are the consumable resource.
**CR_Core_Memory**: adds memory as consumable to CR_CPU_Memory.

After that is done and you have selected the type of resource you want to use as consumable in SLURM all you need to do is add the option `shared=yes` to your default queue and issue the command `scontrol reconfigure` in the node that is being used as controller.

Comment: Where does the option `shared=yes` go?